# Mac OS X Server (Snow Leopard) Mananged Client documentation

Tags: mac, mac-osx-server, user-management, mcx

I'm looking to better understand setting preferences for managed clients...specifically plists for iChat... Where is the most thorough documentation for setting this up (Once/Often)?

It's either not well documented or I'm looking in the wrong place...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See Chapter 10 in [Mac OS X Server User Management](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/UserMgmt_v10.6.pdf). You can find links to this and other useful information on the [Snow Leopard Server support page](http://www.apple.com/support/snowleopardserver/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ask here for specific problems you might have. For docs other than Apple's own admin manuals, maybe have a look at [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224436) or [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430229373).